# How to Focus Documentation Popup in IntelliJ via Keyboard

Tags: intellij-idea

To view quick documentation of a type/parameter/etc. in IntelliJ code editor, I use the Ctrl + Q shortcut. It properly shows the quick documentation popup with the popup having focus so I can scroll it if needed. However, when in the Visualization window (select any table in the Data Sources window and press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + U or right-click | Diagrams | Show Visualization), the quick documentation popup doesn't get focused automatically. As a result, when showing the quick documentation popup for a table, I have to click the popup with mouse to focus it and scroll. Is there a way I can focus the quick documentation popup via keyboard? Or may be configure IntelliJ to auto-focus the quick documentation popup when I show it using Ctrl +Q? I hope this is not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature. Focus stays at the original component (Project View, NavBar menu, etc) to allow you to change selection and update the popup content. Look at the [screencast](http://www.screenr.com/m4e8) I made to explain the feature. 
To work with a diagram I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> shortcut to open diagram in a dedicated editor tab.

Comment: Not a feature since it works correctly in editors but incorrectly in non-editor views (like tree views and diagram views. @CrazyCoder confirms it as a bug.

Comment: Actually it seems you're right. I just checked the screencast and it makes sense. However, there should be a way to focus the documentation popup via keyboard (when you want to scroll its contents) without having to click it using the mouse.

btw, the bug URL is http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82253.

Comment: Also the issue I reported exists in a dedicated diagram editor tab. If you drop a few tables on a diagram editor and then select one and press Ctrl + Q, you'll find there's no way to focus the popup if it has scrollable contents and you want to scroll it.

Comment: There should still be a way to focus the documentation popup so that if you want to view the scrollable contents of the popup, you can do that via the keyboard. I propose that when documentation popup is shown via Ctrl + Q, pressing the same key again (Ctrl + Q) should focus the popup. Of course, this applies to views like diagrams and tree views etc. In code editors, Ctrl + Q should focus the popup automatically (the first time it's shown) as it does today.